# LiveData Observer

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata

In parallel, I download data from a local source and check for updates on the server. But for some reason, the sheet data is not updated. I use Firestore.

Fragment:

```kotlin
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        checkUpdate()
        getData()
    }

    private fun checkUpdate() {
        viewModel.checkUpdate().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
            when(result) {
                is Response.Loading -> { loading() }
                is Response.Success -> {
                    viewModel.updateData()
                }
                is Response.Error -> { error(result.exception) }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun getData() {
        viewModel.getData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
            when(result) {
                is Response.Loading -> { loading() }
                is Response.Success -> { success(result.data) }
                is Response.Error -> { error(result.exception) }
            }
        })
    }
```

ViewModel

```kotlin
    private var data: LiveData<Response<List<Rule>>>

    init {
        data = loadData()
    }

    fun getData() = data

    fun updateData() { data = loadData() }

    private fun loadData() =
        liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Response.Loading)

            val result = repository.getData()
            if (result is Response.Success || result is Response.Error) emit(result)
        }

    fun checkUpdate() =
        liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            val lastUpdateTimestamp = Timestamp(
                preferences.getLong("PREF_RULE_LAST_UPDATE", 0),
                0
            )

            emit(Response.Loading)

            when(val result = repository.checkUpdate(lastUpdateTimestamp)) {
                is Response.Success -> {
                    if (result.data > lastUpdateTimestamp) {
                        try {
                            val editor = preferences.edit()
                            editor.putLong("PREF_RULE_LAST_UPDATE", result.data.seconds)
                            editor.apply()
                            emit(Response.Success(true))
                        } catch (exception: Exception) {
                            emit(Response.Error(exception))
                        }
                    } else {
                        emit(Response.Success(false))
                    }
                }
                is Response.Error -> { emit(result) }
            }
        }
```

Repository

```
    suspend fun getData(): Response<List<Rule>> =
        suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            firebaseFirestore
                .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
                .whereEqualTo("published", true)
                .orderBy("number", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .get(Source.CACHE)
                .addOnSuccessListener { query ->
                    try {
                        val data = arrayListOf<Rule>()
                        query.documents.forEach {document ->
                            document.toObject(RuleDomain::class.java)?.let {
                                it.id = document.id
                                data.add(it.toRule())
                            }
                        }
                        continuation.resume(Response.Success(data))
                    } catch (exception: Exception) {
                        Log.e(TAG, exception.localizedMessage!!)
                        continuation.resume(Response.Error(exception))
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Log.e(TAG, exception.localizedMessage!!)
                    continuation.resume(Response.Error(exception))
                }
        }

    suspend fun checkUpdate(lastUpdateTimestamp: Timestamp): Response<Timestamp> =
        suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            firebaseFirestore
                .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
                .whereGreaterThan("update_timestamp", lastUpdateTimestamp)
                .orderBy("update_timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .get(Source.SERVER)
                .addOnSuccessListener { query ->
                    try {
                        val data = query.documents.first()["update_timestamp"] as Timestamp
                        continuation.resume(Response.Success(data))
                    } catch (exception: Exception) {
                        Log.e(TAG, exception.localizedMessage!!)
                        continuation.resume(Response.Error(exception))
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Log.e(TAG, exception.localizedMessage!!)
                    continuation.resume(Response.Error(exception))
                }
        }
```

I want to replace that the "data" variable is actually being updated since the data appears when the screen is rotated. As far as I know from the documentation `viewModel.getData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { ... })` should be signed while the fragment is alive, and should commit all changes.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to completely abandon part of the code and rewrite it a bit.

Fragment

```kotlin
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        getData()
    }

    private fun getData() {
        viewModel.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
            when(result) {
                is Response.Loading -> { loading() }
                is Response.Success -> { success(result.data) }
                is Response.Error -> { error(result.exception) }
            }
        })
    }
```

ViewModel

```kotlin
    private var _data: LiveData<Response<List<Rule>>>
    val data: LiveData<Response<List<Rule>>>
        get() = _data

    init {
        _data = loadData()
    }

    private fun loadData(): LiveData<Response<List<Rule>>> =
        liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Response.Loading)

            val lastUpdateTimestamp = Timestamp(preferences.getLong("PREF_RULE_LAST_UPDATE", 0), 0)
            val response = repository.getData(lastUpdateTimestamp)

            if (response is Response.Success) {
                val result = response.data

                if (result.containsKey("LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP"))
                    if (result["LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP"] as Timestamp > lastUpdateTimestamp)
                        preferences.put("PREF_RULE_LAST_UPDATE", (result["LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP"] as Timestamp).seconds)

                if (result.containsKey("DATA"))
                    emit(Response.Success(result["DATA"] as List<Rule>))
            }

            if (response is Response.Error)
                emit(response)
        }
```

Repository

```kotlin
    suspend fun getData(timestamp: Timestamp): Response<HashMap<String, Any?>> =
        suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            firebaseFirestore
                .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
                .whereGreaterThan("update_timestamp", timestamp)
                .orderBy("update_timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .get(Source.SERVER)
                .addOnCompleteListener { queryServer ->
                    val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any?>()
                    if (!queryServer.result?.isEmpty!!)
                        hashMap["LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP"] = queryServer.result!!.first().get("update_timestamp") as Timestamp

                    firebaseFirestore
                        .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
                        .whereEqualTo("published", true)
                        .orderBy("number", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                        .get(Source.CACHE)
                        .addOnSuccessListener { queryCache ->
                            try {
                                val data = arrayListOf<Rule>()
                                queryCache.documents.forEach {document ->
                                    document.toObject(RuleDomain::class.java)?.let {
                                        it.id = document.id
                                        data.add(it.toRule())
                                    }
                                }
                                hashMap["DATA"] = data

                                continuation.resume(Response.Success(hashMap))
                            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                                Log.e(TAG, exception.localizedMessage!!)
                                continuation.resume(Response.Error(exception))
                            }
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                            Log.e(TAG, exception.localizedMessage!!)
                            continuation.resume(Response.Error(exception))
                        }
                }
        }
```

Comment: If there is no network connection, an exception is thrown when using Source.SERVER. Therefore, it is probably more correct to replace Source.SERVER with Source.DEFAULT. In any case, Firestore prefers actual data from the server.